# Constrained Optimization in Mathematica

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to do the simplest of constrained optimizations in Mathematica but it just wont work and I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I just want max ln[x]+ln[y] subject to 10=x+y. This can simply be done by hand but Mathematica keeps spitting this out:

NMaximize::nrnum: The function value -2.19476-3.14159 I is not a real number at {x,y} = {10.8291,-0.829053}. >>

General::stop: Further output of NMaximize::nrnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

What's going on? Why cant it solve for the optimal x and y values?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you are trying?

Comment: try adding `x,y>0` to your constraints

Comment: The actual code is NMaximize[{Log[x] + Log[y], x + y == 10}, {x, y}]. How can I add the constraints on x and y?

Comment: Try x+y==10,x>0,y>0 and see what happens.